# WSO2 API Manager authorisation based on HTTP verbs

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, http-verbs

I'm evaluating WSO2 API Manager to organize some corporate APIs.

Is it possible to authorise users based on a combination of resources and HTTP verbs?

To be clear, I need something like this:

> user1 with Access_Token_1, can POST, PUT and DELETE to resource /myresource

whereas

> user2 with Access_Token_2, can only do a GET to the same resource /myresource

any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to have Entitlement Mediator in API Gateway.

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/finegrained-authorization-restful-services-xacml

Thanks & regards,
-Prabath